# Select max value in MS Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need to select the max value in my row column. When I hit line

```
(FindCurrentTimeCard = Val(myreader("Row"))
```

I get an error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

Code:

```
Public Function FindCurrentTimeCard() As Integer
   Dim myconnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
   Dim query As String = "Select MAX(Row) from Table2"
   Dim dbsource As String =("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=S:\Docs\PRODUCTION\Shop Manager\Shop_Manager\Shop_Manager\Database2.accdb;")
   Dim conn = New OleDbConnection(dbsource)
   Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)

   Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        myreader.Read()
        FindCurrentTimeCard = Val(myreader("Row"))
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error Pull Data from Table2")
        FindCurrentTimeCard = 1
    End Try

End Function
```

[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pw2Im.png)

Comment: MAX(Row) is not the same thing as Row.  Try using ExecuteScalar instead.  Side note:  If your code throws an exception, the connection isn't getting closed.  Consider coding with Using - End Using blocks to automatically close and dispose those objects, which would also close in the event of an exception.

Comment: I added my table to the post (Table2) I am not sure what you mean MAX(Row) is not the same thing as Row.

Comment: You should use ExecuteScalar in this case as Lars said, but if you are ever returning more than one value from a query, you should use something like "select max(row) as maxrow, othercolumn, from ..." so that you can access your aggregate columns' values by a column name

Comment: The column you are returning in your query is NOT called Row, so the reader throws that exception.

Comment: What is it called then?

Comment: Call it whatever you want.  `MAX(Row) AS MaxRow` and then your reader would access it `myreader("MaxRow")`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you evaluate an aggregate function (or indeed, any expression performing some operation on a field or fields), the result of such evaluation will be assigned an alias (such as `Expr1000`) unless an alias is otherwise stated.

Hence, when you evaluate the SQL statement:

```sql
select max(table2.row) from table2
```

MS Access will return the result assigned to an alias such as `Expr1000`:

[image]

Hence, the SQL statement does not output a column named `Row`, causing your code to fail when attempting to retrieve the value of such column:

```vb
FindCurrentTimeCard = Val(myreader("Row"))
```

Instead, you should specify an alias to which you may refer in your code, e.g.:

```sql
select max(table2.row) as maxofrow from table2
```

With your function then returning the value associated with such column:

```vb
FindCurrentTimeCard = Val(myreader("maxofrow"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line

```
Public Function FindCurrentTimeCard() As Integer
    Dim CurrentTimeCard As Integer
    'The Using block ensures that your database objects are closed and disposed
    'even it there is an error
    'Pass the connection string directly to the connection constructor
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=S:\Docs\PRODUCTION\Shop Manager\Shop_Manager\Shop_Manager\Database2.accdb;")
        Dim query As String = "Select MAX(Row) from Table2"
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, myconnection)
            Try
                myconnection.Open()
                'since you are only retrieving a single value
                'you can used .ExecuteScalar which gets the value
                'in the first row, first column
                CurrentTimeCard = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
            Catch ex As OleDbException
                MessageBox.Show("Error Pull Data from Table2")
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    'vb.net uses the Return statement to return the value of the function
    Return CurrentTimeCard
End Function
```

Comment: @marc_s i before e except after c. Thanks for the correction. Red Face. :-)